# FSRM move old files to network drive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-server, archive

My file server is getting full. How can I use FSRM (File Server Resource Manager 2012R2) to move old files to another server? I can map a network drive on the file server. But when creating an expired file task, the FSRM won't let me select the network share, only local drives are available.

If FSRM does not work with network share, then I will have to temporarily move those files to a local folder, and then manually move that folder to another server ?

Would Robo Copy do the same?

Answer (score 0):

How about using PowerShell? you could use the move-item CMDLet in a .ps1 script and that use the Task Scheduler to set it as a scheduled task. Below are two link, one with details on Move-Item CMDLet and the other on Task Scheduler

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176910.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871(v=ws.11).aspx

If you want to use FSRM then you will have to create a custom task that uses Robocopy.exe to move the files:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758756(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_CreateCustom

Hope this helps,

Mike.